# [gas][cortex-m23] why does this beq.w results in hard fault?

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler, cortex-m

writing some code to test the CM-23 ARM assembly instruction set, I came across this strange (for me) behaviour regarding the following conditional jump.

`00001240: 0x01f0ef80   beq.w   0x2422 <cmp_r0__r1_failed>`

The containing function has the following directives:

- .arch        armv8-m.base
- .syntax      unified
- .code        16
- .thumb_func

From the [Generic User Guide rev. r1p0](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5eff4394cafe527e86f5b3c4?token=), it is stated that B{cond} has usage limits as follows [−256 bytes to +254 bytes].
The effective jump in this case is about 0x200, but the .w suffix should extend such range at least to 16-bit realm.

During building, the assembler gives no error / warning and the overall process is completed. Then the Hard Fault happens (pointing at such instruction as the culprit).

If I wrote an illegal instruciton, at least I was hoping for the assembler to complain.

What am I missing here? Thanks for any clue about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in the cortex-m23 technical reference manual that

> This processor is an implementation of the ARMv8-M baseline architecture.

Then in the armv8-m architectural reference manual.

> Armv7-M compatibility requires the Main Extension.

And you can see in the armv7-m document that the wide conditional branches are armv7-m only.  As well as not see them in the armv6-m architectural reference manual.

Note the two main types of arm documents are the technical reference manual for each core and architectural reference manual for each architecture.  And those documents are pretty good, other ARM documents and web pages are not so good and misleading if not wrong.

If you are saying that the tools are generating code it should not then file a ticket with the binutils folks.